# UICollectionView io11 - top inset

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, ios11, safearealayoutguide

Guys, I'm migrating my app in ios-11, and I can't manage to make my UICollectionView full screen.
So, I went through StackOverflow, as we all do, and I found these 2 topics :

1. Uncheck Safe Area Relative Margins of the superView
2. Set de Content Inset to None instead of Automatic

These 2 tricks worked pretty well for all my UISrollViews

and UITableViews in my project, But not for UICollectionView.

Do you guys have any idea?
Thanks.

[image: iPhone X]
[image: iPhone 8]

Answer (score 1):

To change how the safe area is applied, modify the contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior property.

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```